# To write a .bat file which will search for a string and update the old string with new one

Tags: batch-file

I want to search and replace string of the format IND A***B***C***  (where * in a number between0 to 9) in a file with some known string like IND A000B103C123

there are many  files in which string is present.And I have to update the same string is all  files eg."IND A110B123C112" .here 'IND' and 'A' 'B' 'C'  is  always same in both old and new version string

I want to writ a script (batch file) so that when run the batch file and give the new string as input, it will replace the old string with the new one

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: 1) You haven't asked a question. 2) You haven't shown any effort to do this yourself, including searching previous questions here about finding and replacing strings with a batch file. 3) You're doing it wrong. `#define`s that you're going to need to modify regularly belong in a separate header file that's included everywhere the value is needed; when the `#define` changes, you simply change the single place in the header file and then recompile your code.

Comment: It's not about C actually,My problem is each time I have to manually update the version string before starting compilation, so I want to write a script such that it will search and update the string. I gave the #define XXX YYY because some logic may come out to search from that @KenWhite

Comment: You specifically say "In my .c files", and you're talking about updating `#define`s. That's "about C actually", and the logic applies to other languages that can use include files as well. The first two points still apply regardless of what you're actually asking (which you still have not edited to do).

Comment: JREPL.BAT from @dbenham this will do the trick http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044

Comment: Also, [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm), as in `sed -i -r -e 's/regexp/replacement/g' *.c`.  You're re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @KenWhite  Ok so you want to know what effor I have given to solve this problem, finding any text by command

Comment: @KenWhite  finding any text by command prompt can be done by using command  Findstr xyz abc.txt but since I want to replace text so only this command is not enough. For replacement we can use command powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File myFile.txt" ,but here we know the string to be replaced, in my case I don't know the exact old string . Old string will be of form IND A***B***C*** .some wild character concepts I tried but it's throwing error.Do you have any solution for this?Plz come out

Comment: @KenWhite  : I got the solution to my problem how to do it. can you suggest me how to  delete a line(I will search for line in which the string is present  and I will replace the old line with the new line) a line and replace it with the new line

Comment: That question has been asked here before as well. Search for it with `[batch-file] replace line` or `[batch-file] delete line`. Don't be helpless - put a little effort into finding things yourself instead of just asking us to to it.

Comment: thanks for giving me some direction to proceed. I have no intention of wasting mine or your time.I was jst researching on the command of DOS and their options @KenWhite

Comment: if I am able to do if windows, I have to writ it for linux also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do that in a very simple way using my FindRepl.bat program:

```
< theFile.txt FindRepl "A\d\d\dB\d\d\dC\d\d\d" "A110B123C112"
```

In previous *regular expression* the `\d` specify "any digit". FindRepl.bat is an hybrid Batch-JScript program that performs this type of find-replacements tasks (and many more) in a very efficient way. The JScript language comes pre-installed in any Windows version from XP on. You may download FindRepl.bat program from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) and place it in the same folder of your Batch solution or, better yet, in a folder of PATH variable, so you may use FindRepl in any other similar problem.

Comment: I appretiate your suggestion,it's working also. But I can not use  the script which I can not explain each and every single word :(

Comment: and if possible , I need some simple script like search for IND A*" replace with IND AXXXBXXXCXXX" where * is any number of char,digit or alphabat between 'A' and ". Thanks